# Python: how to find intersection of two lists (i need a lenght of intersection, actually) if there are duplicates?

Tags: python

Let me have thse two lists:

```
a = ['a','b','c','a','a']
b = ['a','b','d']
```

I need to calculate Jaccard distance = (union-intersect)/union, but I know there gonna be duplicates in each list, and I want to count them, so intersect lenght for the example would be  2 and Jaccard distance = (8-2)/8

How can I do that? first thought is to joint lists and then remove elements one by one...

UPDATE:
probably I had to stress more that I need to count dublicates;

here is my working solution, but it is quite ugly:

```
a = [1,2,3,1,1]
b = [2,1,1, 6,5]

import collections
aX = collections.Counter(a)
bX = collections.Counter(b)

r1 = [x for x in aX if x in bX]
print r1

print sum((min(aX[x], bX[x]) for x in r1))

>>> 3
```

Comment: What would be the desired output in your case? And what output do you get?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a','b','c','a','a']
b = ['a','b','d']
c = list(set(b).intersection(a))
['a','b']
```

Note sets will discard duplicates!

Answer (score 1):

To the get the [jaccard index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between two lists a and b:

```
def jaccard_distance(a,b):
    a = set(a)
    b = set(b)
    c = a.intersection(b)
    return float(len(a) + len(b) - len(c)) /(len(a) + len(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my working solution, but it is quite ugly:

```
a = [1,2,3,1,1]
b = [2,1,1, 6,5]

import collections
aX = collections.Counter(a)
bX = collections.Counter(b)

r1 = [x for x in aX if x in bX]
print r1

print sum((min(aX[x], bX[x]) for x in r1))

>>> 3
```